# React-infinite-calendar range selection

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datepicker, react-redux

I am facing issues with `onSelect` event for range selection in react-infinite-calendar. Can any one suggest me with answers ? I want to select start date and end date and get those values to pass to the state.

Comment: Did you get any solution? Can you share it??

Answer (score 3):

JSX

```
<InfiniteCalendar
    Component={withRange(Calendar)}
    height={350}
    min={new Date(2017,8,1)}
    selected={this.state.selectedDates}
    layout={'portrait'}
    width={'100%'}
    onSelect={this.onCalendarSelect}
/>
```

onCalendarSelectCode

```
onCalendarSelect = (e) => {
        if (e.eventType === 3) {
            this.setState({ selectedDates: {
                start: e.start,
                end: e.end,
            } });
        }
    }
```

on select with range functionality will return an object with start, end, and eventType. Event type of 3 will indicate user has selected a start and end. You can then set this to state.